# CrawlSpider with Splash, only first link is crawled & processed

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy with Splash. Here is what I have in my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import logging

class MainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'main'
    allowed_domains = ['www.somesite.com']

    script = '''
    function main(splash, args)
      splash.private_mode_enabled = false

      my_user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'

      headers = {
        ['User-Agent'] = my_user_agent,
        ['Accept-Language'] = 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        ['Referer'] = 'https://www.google.com'
      }

      splash:set_custom_headers(headers)

      url = args.url

      assert(splash:go(url))

      assert(splash:wait(2))

      -- username input
      username_input = assert(splash:select('#username'))
      username_input:focus()
      username_input:send_text('myusername')
      assert(splash:wait(0.3))

      -- password input
      password_input = assert(splash:select('#password'))
      password_input:focus()
      password_input:send_text('mysecurepass')
      assert(splash:wait(0.3))

      -- the login button
      login_btn = assert(splash:select('#login_btn'))
      login_btn:mouse_click()
      assert(splash:wait(4))

      return splash:html()
    end
    '''

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="(//div[@id='sidebar']/ul/li)[7]/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_request='use_splash'),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url = 'https://www.somesite.com/login', callback = self.post_login, endpoint = 'execute', args = {
            'lua_source': self.script
        })

    def use_splash(self, request):
        request.meta.update(splash={
            'args': {
                'wait': 1,
            },
            'endpoint': 'render.html',
        })

        return request

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if not isinstance(response, (HtmlResponse, SplashJsonResponse, SplashTextResponse)):
            return

        seen = set()

        for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response) if lnk not in seen]

            if links and rule.process_links:
                links = rule.process_links(links)

            for link in links:
                seen.add(link)
                r = self._build_request(n, link)

                yield rule.process_request(r)

    def post_login(self, response):
       logging.info('hey from login!')

       with open('post_login_response.txt', 'w') as f:
           f.write(response.text)
           f.close()

    def parse_item(self, response):
        logging.info('hey from parse_item!')

        with open('post_search_response.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.text)
            f.close()
```

I came across [this](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/92) and I've tried to implement things the same way, but still, `prase_item` is never run. In the logs, I never get `hey from parse_item!`

I'm not sure what I'm missing. The full log output can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/1gNsLLJS)

Comment: maybe you should use a callback inside your post_login function? I also work much with Scrapy and also with scrapysplash and this is the way I always write my crawlers

Comment: Is that required? I thought scrapy would just look at the rules and decide where to go from there!

Comment: I can not gurantee, that it is definitely required, but this is how I always work with it :) but I see you already found a solution (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ditched the Crawl Spider and converted to a regular spider, and things are working fine now.